# Count "01" sequences in input signal

Tags: vhdl

My goal is to count the number of "01" sequences in `iaI` array. 
I tried following code but it does not work as I assumed.

```
entity prob35 is
port (
    iaI : in   std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
    oaO : out  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
);
end prob35;

architecture Behavioral of prob35 is
    signal counter : integer := 0;
begin
process(iaI)
begin
    for i in 1 to 11 loop
        if (iaI(i-1)='1' and iaI(i)='0') then
            counter<=counter+1;
        end if;
    end loop;
    oaO<=conv_std_logic_vector(counter,oaO'length);
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Simulating you'd get one increment of counter for each iaI event. Signal updates  don't occur while any process has yet to resume or subsequently suspend during a simulation cycle, counter can only be incremented by 1. Also note there is no provision to 'clear' counter. You could use a variable for counter here. assigning it to 0 before the loop statement. The code would represent an 11 bit hamming weighting network fed by 11 gates detecting "01" with an output that can a numeric range of 0 to 6.

Comment: What is the expected result? What result did you receive for what stimuli? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There is significant difference between signals and variables in vhdl. While the variable takes the value of assignment immediately, signal in sequential code (like process) are used to create flip-flops, which inherently do not immediately take the value of their assignment. You should use variable to achieve desired functionality here.

```
entity prob35 is
port (
    iaI : in   std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
    oaO : out  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
);
end prob35;

architecture Behavioral of prob35 is
begin
process(iaI)
    variable counter : unsigned(2 downto 0) := "000";
begin
    counter := "000";
    for i in 1 to 11 loop
        if (iaI(i-1)='1' and iaI(i)='0') then
            counter := counter + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;
    oaO <= std_logic_vector(counter);
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: To make the process re-entrant, you'd want to assign counter to "000" before the loop statement.

Comment: @user1155120 you are right here, sory for my mistake of haste, edited.

Comment: @Daniel Glad to help, if this solves pointed problem you may consider [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. Please also read what @ user1155120 pointed out in previous comment about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so in case of vhdl provide testbench stimuli to make it easier to check your problem and help you.